# How to make tag categories, but if the size is long then it will automatically fall down

Tags: view, label, titanium

[image]

How to make tag categories like above, i tried using the code below

```
<View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE"  layout="horizontal">
    <View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="10dp">
        <Label height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" left="10dp" right="10dp" top="5dp" bottom="5dp" text="Tidak ada layanan pesan antar"/>
    </View>
    <View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="10dp">
        <Label height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" left="10dp" right="10dp" top="5dp" bottom="5dp" text="Makan di tempat"/>
    </View>
    <View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="10dp">
        <Label height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" left="10dp" right="10dp" top="5dp" bottom="5dp" text="Alkohol Tidak Tersedia"/>
    </View>
    <View height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" right="10dp">
        <Label height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="Ti.UI.SIZE" left="10dp" right="10dp" top="5dp" bottom="5dp" text="Tempat duduk di luar"/>
    </View>
</View>
```

The result is

[image: image2]

The view is not falling down if the size is too long, but keep filling the blank space of view parent. I dont know how to make it automatically falling down like the first image. Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting horizontalwrap to false?

Comment: could you show your tss file? Because when I just use your xml and add backgroundColor and borderRadius I'll end up with the result you want to have. The 2 right boxes don't break. But try setting wordWrap to false

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a fix height. With that, there is no line break